# Prolog maximum term size

Tags: prolog

I'm considering using some very long terms to describe coordinates on an xy grid, and/or the entire xy grid itself.  I tried to find some info in documentation, but didn't have any luck.

What's the maximum size of a compound term, and where can I find this information?  I'm currently using SWI, but may use other Prologs too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relevant to your question are the standard flags `max_arity` and `bounded`. The `max_arity` flag can have the value `unbounded`, meaning only memory limits the number of arguments of a compound term, are a natural number. The `bounded` flag is a boolean flag. If `true`, it means that the also standard flags `max_integer` and `min_integer` specify the representable integers. Also relevant, but unfortunately not expressed by a standard flag, is the maximum atom size if not unbound; here you will need to check the documentation of the Prolog system.